# Getting errors when loading images in class definition

Tags: c#, image

I'm working on a hobby chess project when I load the piece images it throws an exception that the image cannot be found. I know this is not the case, it has worked before and when I load them in a method it does work. They are located in the right place and the file paths are correct. At first the code used the Bitmap class instead of the Image class, which gave the same result.

My main reason for loading the images in class definition is that I use most images several times and I want to make sure every image is loaded only once.

This shows the class definition and the first button, but an image is loaded for every piece.

```
public partial class PieceButton : Button
{
    private static readonly Image blackBishop = Image.FromFile("images/black_bishop.gif");
```

Later I will apply the loaded image to the button when a piece moves to it.
The class inherits Button because the default button behaviour is very usefull.
The images are .gif because then the button background remains visible (fields are white or black).

So my question is: How can I load these images properly in the class definition?

Comment: Can you post the code from when you loaded it in a method?

Comment: *"it throws an exception that the image cannot be found. I know this is not the case"* - Sure about that?  I'm inclined to believe the runtime.  You realize that you are initializing this object statically from a relative path, correct?

Comment: Additionally (and this is not meant to serve as an answer to this question, but to give you an alternative path to take) you may want to consider adding the images as resources in Resources.resx.  If you're using Visual Studio it's much easier than what you're trying to do above.

Comment: @Ed S, yes would that matter? I assume the base path is always my debug folder, where I copied the images to. The reason I know it works is because it has worked before.
I'll try adding the images to my resources.

Comment: Adding images in the resource files is a much better solution. If you answer this question with that I will accept it. Loading the image:

this.Image = Chess.Properties.Resources.white_bishop;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding the images as resources to Resources.resx and have Visual Studio worry about generating the code to actually turn the underlying data into an Image object.  This has a number of advantages, the largest being that any issues (like an image not being present) will be caught at compile time because VS generates Properties.Resources.whatever for you ahead of time.

You will also get the "Load Images Once" behavior that you desire